JSON interpretation of chunked data
I need to locate the parameters for a specific object returned from a remote server in JSON format. But the number of objects on the server is always increasing so the JSON responses get larger and larger. I anticipate when there are hundreds of thousands of objects, the JSON response will exceed the memory capacity to hold them all at once in a json.load(). So it would probably be necessary to get the remote data in chunks instead. But will I have to write my own parser in this case as the JSON input will be spaning chunks?
In the example below, I must locate the object named 'ID-98349' among all the objects returned. Once I find it, I will be extracting many of the key/value parameters associated with this specific object. But of course, given this is coming as a chunked stream, the string of data could be split across chunks at any point in the string.
Is there a set of tools/functions to allow me to find a JSON item arriving in a stream?
{
 ["objects"]: [
    {
        "Reference": "obj-1",
        "name": "ID-123",
        < a long list of key/value parameters>
    }
    {
        "Reference": "obj-2",
        "name": "ID-567",
        < a long list of key/value parameters>
    }
    ...
    {
        "Reference": "obj-4982",
        "name": "ID-98349",
        < a long list of key/value parameters>
    }
   ]
}
 


Is the number of k/v pairs constant?

Is the remote server a publicly available service? Is it under your control?

ijson , yajl or jq may be some possibilities

Yes the number of k/v pair would be constant. The server is operated as a service from a company for a fee so we are not in control of the remote server. We are the client in this situation.

Is the server adhering to server-sent-events or similar protocol? Because your JSON seems to be missing the commas between the chunks.

The point of this question is how to deal with a JSON that might be so large that you can't read it all in at once, so the data you are searching for could be split between two chunks read at one time. The syntax of the example may not be formatted correctly and missing a comma,  but that does not change the purpose of the question.
